# Infinite trascendence degree implies existence of a homomorphism

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I'm having trouble with a problem from Morandi's *Field & Galois Theory*:
Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $F$ be a subfield of $K$ with $\text{trdeg}(K/F)=\infty$. Show that there is an $F-$homomorphism $\varphi:K \to K$ that is not an $F$-automorphism.

I know for a fact that if $\text{trdeg}(K/F)<\infty$ this is not possible because we can permute the elements of the basis and every homomorphism would me surjective.

Can anybody give me an example of such homomorphism? I tried sending every trascendental to $0$, and sending some $k$-th trascendental to a ($k+1$)th one but I always have the same problem trying to make sense of $\varphi(a+b)$ and $\varphi(ab)$ when a,b are both trascendental over $F$

Comment: I'd say in general the difficulty is to find $E/F$ such that $K = \overline{E(( x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}})}$ and  $\varphi(x_n) = x_{n+1}$ is well-defined.

Comment: Can you please tell me what would $\varphi(x_n + x_m)$ and $\varphi(x_nx_m)$ be? I don't understand how to extend $\varphi$ to every element

Comment: $\varphi(f(x_0,\ldots,x_{m-1})) = f(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ is an isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}( x_0,\ldots,x_{m-1}) \to \mathbb{Q}( x_1,\ldots,x_m)$. It extends to an isomorphism $\overline{\mathbb{Q}( x_0,\ldots,x_{m-1})} \to \overline{\mathbb{Q}( x_1,\ldots,x_m)}$ and $\bigcup_{m \to \infty}\overline{\mathbb{Q}( x_0,\ldots,x_{m-1})} \to \bigcup_{m \to \infty}\overline{\mathbb{Q}( x_1,\ldots,x_m)}$